# juju can't run wordpress on a local machine and agent-state is pending?

Tags: juju, wordpress

Following [this](http://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html) instruction and using **juju switch local** for installing on my laptop as local host, I get the below error when I run `juju status`,why?

`error: container "onrea-local-machine-1" is already create`

Also, ***agent-state*** is pending. see here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7056689/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a previous local provider instance did not get destroyed properly.

You can destroy the current one with:

```
# If using juju 1.17.x
juju destroy-environment -y local
# If using juju 1.16.x
juju destroy-environment -y -e local
```

And then look at the current lxc images:

```
sudo lxc-ls --fancy
```

Any that start with "onrea-local" will be ones that juju things it created.

You can remove them with:

```
sudo lxc-destroy -n onrea-local-machine-1
```

And so on.

This is a limitation of the local provider, and one what we are looking to fix very soon (the clean destruction that is).

Comment: Thanks, Now I have a new problem: http://askubuntu.com/q/431441/152405 (This is because of reinstalling juju!) | `ls /var/lib/lxc` => enpty!