# (JuJu) How to install "ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz" manually?

Tags: juju

Because of an error over using [juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/install/) , I've downloaded these two files:

```
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/precise/release-20140227/ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/server/releases/precise/release-20140227/ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
```

These two files are not *compile-able*. They are VMs! and I don't know where should I extract them. How should I install them?

Here is **ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.tar.gz** content:

`precise-server-cloudimg-amd64.img`

`precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-floppy`

`precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-loader`

`precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-virtual`

A new error that I got: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7057154/

Comment: The error seems to indicate the server image might have not downloaded correctly? Can you tear down the environment and try it again?

Comment: I've tried it many times. It seems that is a downloading problem the same as this issue on large files for some networks: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/4872

Answer (score 1):

That vmlinuz file you see over there, is *bootable*. So you do not need to install. Just **append** it to a virtual drive.

Using Virtualbox, I think you could start using the OS immediately. It says "virtual" so you won't be able boot the OS without such third party app.

So no manual installation is necessary, because there is no installation at all.

EDIT: Answer to your first comment.

1. Use your image file in Virtualbox by opening the img file within Virtualbox.
2. According to the report, you've already chosen a couple of services. So you're better off asking **whether you want to solve the Jojo error or install the OS manually** because your question according to the title is the latter one, in which I already explained  its solution above. *But if you want to solve the error, then the details are below.*
3. Your error is: GZIP failed to extract your archive at line 33; saying *"Unexpected EOF in archive"*. My guess is the file is corrupt. It is probable that you have failed to completely download the file due to some bad connection.

To check this, generate the MD5 sum of the file on your hard drive with the hash I found [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release-20140227/MD5SUMS). If they're not same, all you need to do is to retry the download.

So you last question was how to introduce it to juju; you need to solve this error beforehand by trying this solution out.

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: how to import them to Virtualbox? there is 2 tar.gz files. besides,  acording [this issue](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7057154/), `juju` is trying to fetch them and I've downloaded them manually. I want to know how introduce them to juju!

Comment: Look at my edit.